# Store and invoke an event (VB.NET .NET 2.0)

Tags: vb.net, events, delegates

I think know how to do this in C# but I'm having syntax trouble in VB.NET because I need to take advantage of the 'handles' event stuff.

I have different events that I somehow (probably delegate) need stored in a property of an attribute (I just add an attribute to a property linking to the corresponding event).

E.g.

```
<BindEvent(EventThing)>_
Public ReadOnly Property IsTrue() As Boolean
  Get
    Return True
  End Get
End Property
```

They need to be events so that other programmers can use the VB.NET handles keyword on methods.

```
Public Delegate Sub TestEvent(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Object)
Public Event E As TestEvent

Public Sub Test() Handles E
End Sub
```

These properties are already raising a general event, which I am catching, determining the related property and thus getting the related attribute (and delegate/event).  I want to then raise the event that's related.

If I just use a delegate tied to the particular event that won't raise other handlers will it?

I also want to avoid having to write a sub for each property that just uses Raise Event on the event type if possible as this seems redundant.

e.g. avoid:

```
Public Event E As TestEvent
Public Sub CallE(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Object)
  RaiseEvent E(sender, e)
End Sub
<BindDelegate(DelegateToCallE)>_
Public ReadOnly Property IsTrue() As Boolean
  Get
    Return True
  End Get
End Property
```

Comment: can you give an example of what you want in C#? if it's a syntax problem i could probably help more, I just can't understand what you want right now, kind of confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public Class foo

    Public Event TestEvent()

End Class


Public Class bar
    Dim WithEvents x As New foo
    Public Sub HandleEvent() Handles x.TestEvent
    End Sub
End Class
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you are trying to do.  Are you by any chance looking for syntax like this:

```
Class BindEventAttribute
    Inherits System.Attribute

    Public Delegate Sub TestEvent()
    Public Custom Event EventToRaise As TestEvent
       AddHandler(ByVal value As TestEvent)
          REM TODO: code what happens when anyone calls AddHandler on this event
       End AddHandler

       RemoveHandler(ByVal value As TestEvent)
          REM TODO: code what happens when enyone calls RemoveHandler on this event
       End RemoveHandler

       RaiseEvent()
          REM TODO: code what happens when anyone calls RaiseEvent on this event
       End RaiseEvent
    End Event
End Class
```